# Initialize smart pointer with rvalue

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'd like to understand if the problem  I have while creating `new_class2` is because `std::make_shared` returns an `rvalue`. And if so, what are the other ways to initialize the object, despite the one that I already made in `new_class`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> common_number;

public:
    Foo(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> &integer_vec) : common_number(integer_vec)
    {
        for (auto &v : *integer_vec)
        {
            std::cout << v << std::endl;
        }
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
    }
    void addTerm(int integer)
    {
        common_number->push_back(integer);
    }
    void print()
    {
        for (auto &v : *common_number)
        {
            std::cout << v << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {};
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> int_ptr = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(vec);

    Foo new_class(int_ptr);
    Foo new_class1(int_ptr);

    new_class1.addTerm(5);
    new_class.print();

    new_class.addTerm(1);
    new_class1.print();

    Foo new_class2(std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(vec));

    return 0;
}
```

I do  get the compilation error:

`error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::shared_ptr<int>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::shared_ptr<int>’ Foo new_class2(std::make_shared<int>(1));’`

Comment: `Foo(std::shared_ptr<int> &integer_)` should be `Foo(std::shared_ptr<int> integer_)` since it is a sink.  Otherwise it should be `Foo(int integer_)` if it is not a sink.

Comment: pass by `const std::shared_ptr<int>&` ? You can't take mutable references to temporaries and rightfully so

Comment: @Eljay if he doesn't stores / copies it, it should be passed by reference. `std::shared_ptr` has some overhead when copying

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann • if he doesn't store or copy it (i.e., it is not a sink), then it should not be passed as as shared_ptr at all.

Comment: @Eljay yeah thats true

Comment: I used `int` as an easier way to test the concept. @Eljay what do you mean by `sink`?

Comment: A former co-worker of mine wrote up use case scenarios and guidelines: [smart pointer parameters](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) (a **sink** means the parameter is consumed, so it is suitable for moving from a parameter into a member variables.)

Comment: just updated for a more "realistic scenario". I don't know if that changes some comments

Comment: So you have the usual question, really: whether to pass by value or `const&` or `&&` when consuming an argument. You could search for plenty info about that. But I think the general answer would be to pass by value and `move()` into the member. If really needed, you could instead have separate `const&` and `&&` overloads of the constructor, since an rvalue can of course bind to an rvalue reference `&&`. But that's unlikely to be needed unless you can benchmark and prove it's a bottleneck anywhere

Comment: Change `Foo(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> &integer_vec) : common_number(integer_vec)` to `Foo(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> integer_vec) : common_number(std::move(integer_vec))` instead.

Comment: @Eljay even if I change the `integer` for another class?

Comment: @underscore_d thx for your comments. I will do more research on that.

Comment: The `shared_ptr` is about ownership.  If you are not federating ownership, then a `shared_ptr` should not be passed in or returned.  (Likewise with `unique_ptr`.)  If you are transferring ownership, then **yes** the same pattern, regardless of the T in the `shared_ptr<T>`.

Comment: Where is new_class2...?

Comment: end of the `main`, right before the `return` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Elijay and @underscore_d proposed in the comments, passing by value and then using `move()` would be the recommended approach

```
Foo(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> integer_vec) : common_number(std::move(integer_vec))
    {
        for (auto &v : *integer_vec)
        {
            std::cout << v << std::endl;
        }
    }
```